# Rendering dynamically changing components in a template

Tags: angularjs, templates, ionic-framework, components

I want to render custom components dynamically inside a `ion-slide` container. And I would like to be able to specify the components which should be used outside of the template, for example in a list in my component to keep it configurable.

Some component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  templateUrl: 'myComponent.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

My HomePage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class 

  pages = [
    {
      name: "some page",
      template: "<myComponent></myComponent>"
    },
    {
      name: "some other page",
      template: "<myComponent></myComponent>"
    }
  ]

  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

and my template for my HomePage:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-slides
    #slides
    [autoplay]="10*1000"
    loop="true"
  >
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let page of pages">
      {{ page.name }}
      <div [innerHTML]="page.template"></div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

The problem is that using `innerHtml` in the template does not seem to work. The template which I'm trying to inject in the `div` seems to get swallowed and the component is not rendered.

So how could I inject a component in my template without explicitly adding it to the template but rather adding it to a list inside my HomePage or even in a config file?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-sanitize` and `ng-bind-html` so that the innerHTML expression is evaluated and rendered. [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)
Or just actually use the component as the way you're doing this seems to circumvent the utility of components to the best of my knowledge in a way that is not necessarily consequential, but from the code you posted most definitely is.
i.e.

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let page of pages" ng-switch="page.name">
<myComponent ng-switch-when="some page"/>
<myComponent1 ng-switch-when="some other page"/>
</ion-slide>
```

There are other ways that this could be approached as well.